# What is include.txt and exclude.txt in my Downloads folder?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bash, files, gnome-documents

My Downloads folder has two files that I'm not sure what they are there for: "include.txt" and "exclude.txt."
"include.txt' only shows "sources/boot.wim."
"exclude.txt" only shows "sources/."
Does anyone know why these are there and what uses them? I want to delete them but don't want to mess something up.

Comment: You probably created them by accident when running some command. Check out command history for those filenames

Comment: I would be shocked if there's software that stores important files in a users Downloads folder (unless that's where you told it to put them)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of those files are essential to the operation of your Ubuntu system, and can be safely deleted without damaging your Ubuntu system.

None of those files were created by Ubuntu automatically. You created them somehow. They might be important to some project of yours -- we don't know anything about you or your projects.

If you are curious about the contents of those files, then read them.

The Downloads directory is not a typical place where software gets installed to. It is, however, a normal place where files that you click in a web browser get downloaded to.

Comment: Yup, I read the contents, which is what I mentioned in the question. All that was in them was:
"include.txt' only shows "sources/boot.wim." "exclude.txt" only shows "sources/."
I just deleted them. Thanks for the quick reply!